# Scripting `rm` and `rm -i`

Tags: shell, shell-script, rm

I want to create a script that whenever there are more than three files being removed, it invokes `rm -i` by default. I know it will go in initialization files but can't seem to get it working.

So far:

```
if [$file -ge 3]; then
  rm -i 
  exit 0 
else
  rm
exit 1
```

Answer (score 15):

The function given in @Tim's answer will work on any system running bash. However, GNU `rm` already has an option for what you need (from `man rm`):

```
   -I     prompt  once  before  removing more than three
          files, or  when  removing  recursively.   Less
          intrusive  than -i, while still giving protec‐
          tion against most mistakes
```

So, if you have GNU `rm` (which you should if you're running Linux) all you need is to add this line to your `/.bashrc`:

```
alias rm='rm -I'
```

This will prompt before deleting more than 3 files, but it will not ask for confirmation for every file, if you confirm the action, all files will be deleted.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me, add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
rm() {
   if [ "$#" -ge 3 ]; then
        command rm -i "$@"
   else
        command rm "$@"
   fi
}
```

This will make an `rm` function which will be called instead of `/bin/rm` every time you execute `rm`.

`"$#"` expands to the number of arguments passed.

Comment: i put that in bashrc, and started the terminal, it gave me an error that [0 Command not found rm: missing operand

Comment: @user2805361 Did you copy that code exactly? The error is strange (did you copy-paste it?) but it looks like you wrote `[$#` instead of `[ $#` (missing space). Also this code is designed for use in a script or in a function.

Comment: I tried the edit still the same error when i start a new terminal. and yes code is exact, can i use the same code in .bashrc though?

Comment: @user2805361 As Gilles said, if you want to put this in your `.bashrc`, you should make it into a function. Try wrapping this exact code in `rm () { ... }`.

Comment: `if [ $# -ge 3 ]; then
 (rm -i "${@}")
else
 (rm "${@}")
fi` \Whats wrong here? without the curly braces it still gives an error

Comment: @Tim Your answer works fine with a glob pattern: the shell has to expand the glob before actually calling the command/function/script,...

Comment: after adding this to bashrc, when i start the terminal and remove three files, it should prompt me but it isnt doing that

Comment: ` if [ $# -ge 3 ]; then
 'rm -i' "$@" \
else
 'rm' "$@"
fi` i added that backslash and terminal didnd give error but still when deleting it dosent prompt

Comment: @user2805361 I edited the answer, if you want it in your .bashrc, you'll need something like that. Try the updated answer and let us know.

Comment: Ahh thanks @JosephR. that is the part I wasn't sure about!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise still portable way to do it:

```
rm() {
  command rm $([ ${#} -gt 3 ] && echo \-i) "$@"
}
```

I would however recommend to avoid changing `rm` semantics, see this [reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269685/2594) for details.