# Workaround for missing rm -I option on OSX?

Tags: bash, osx, rm

I'd like to do this, on OSX:

```
alias rm="rm -I"
```

In GNU rm, this means that `rm` will prompt if it's recursive or if it's deleting three or more files, but not if it's just deleting one or two files. However, OSX (Mavericks) rm doesn't support this.

Is there a workaround so that `rm` will prompt, once, when deleting several files, but won't prompt for single files, or for every single file in mass deletes?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92085/117549

Comment: @ThomasDickey Agreed, but more specifically for his case: [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92085/79743).

Answer (score 0):

The linked answer gave me a good start, but was a bit simplistic - it triggered if you had a glob matching 3 files, but not if you were doing `rm -rf foo`.

So this works for me in `~.bash_profile`:

```
rmf() {
    if [ "$1" == "-rf" ]; then
        read -r -p "Sure you want to delete '${2}' [y/N]? " response
        if [[ $response =~ ^(yes|y| ) ]]; then
            command rm "$@"
        fi
    else
        command rm "$@"
    fi
}
alias rm=rmf
```