# `rm` prompt when given more than one file

Tags: bash, rm

For some reason, my finger memory has converted `mv` to `rm`. Until I manage to retrain those fingers, how might I have `rm` prompt **when provided multiple locations** (one of which likely does not exist)?

I know that the `-I` option will prompt on more than three files, and the `-i` will prompt on every file, but I need something similar that will prompt on more than one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define function `rm` in your bash and check number of args. If there is only 1 arg, them run `command rm` to call the original command. Otherwise print a warning.

Something like:

```
function rm()
{
    if (( $# > 1 )); then
        read -r -p "sure? [y/n] " response
        case $response in
            [yY])
                command rm "$@"
                ;;
            *)
                echo "ignored"
                ;;
        esac
    else
        command rm "$@"
    fi
}
```

One thing to improve in my function is first to scan all parameters and if a parameter starts with `-` then consider the parameter as an option. So that function `rm` handles input like `rm -f 1.txt`.

Comment: Thank you, the `if` was the key. I had a hard time trying to concoct that!

Comment: Any reason not to just say `function rm { if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then command rm -i "$@"; else command rm "$@"; fi; }`?

Comment: Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74045/135943 re your function defining syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Do frequent backups, use snapshots (à la time machine) if your file system is `ZFS` or `btrfs`, train your fingers to use the right commands, but I would advise to avoid changing `rm` behavior and semantics.

Doing it will sooner or later backfire, just like the obnoxious `alias rm="rm -i"`...

What I would advise instead in your case would be, when running interactive shells, to have `rm` disabled and being substituted by a custom `rm` that will do its original job. e.g. append these lines to your `.bashrc`

```
rm() {
    echo "rm disabled, use myRM instead"
}
alias myRM="command rm"
```

The annoyance created by the new `rm` function will be more efficient to help you getting rid of the typing mistake and you likely quickly cease to type `rm`.

While this advice looks counterproductive, the reason why I suggest doing it this way is there is no risk for you to be accustomed to a non standard still working behavior for such a dangerous Unix command. Sooner or later, you'll be logged under an account and/or another system without the hack in place and you'll remove files with no security prompt to save them.

On the other hand, if you get used to type `myRM` to remove files, doing it on foreign systems will be harmless.

Finally, should you nevertheless want to overload the `rm` command, here is a concise way to do it:

```
rm() {
  echo command rm $([ ${#} -gt 1 ] && echo \-i) "$@"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, frequent backups won't help when I'm trying to move a few files that I just created (which is the case). For some reason I see that I've made the same mistake twice, so I'm trying to make making the mistake harder.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It does not solve the problem nor provide a workaround. “Change your habits” is explicitly rules out in the question.

Comment: @ dotancohen, yes, backups won't help for recently created files. Snapshots might save some of them though. ZFS snapshots are very lightweight so you can make one snapshot every minute and keep them for say, a couple of hours. Answer updated anyway with more explanations and a suggestion.

Comment: You are 100% correct about working on other systems. In fact, I do often work on other systems and adding a mental speedbump before the rm command sounds like a great idea. I even added a `sleep 1` line for it to sink in.